# undefined method `column_names' for Module:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

I wan't to test a has_many association on a class:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modules
end
```

For this I wrote a test (Rspec):

```
describe Course do
  it { should have_many(:modules) }
end
```

For some reason however this test fails:

```
1) Course should have many modules
 Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:modules) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `column_names' for Module:Class
 # ./spec/models/course_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Does someone has an idea why this test fails? I created a Module class:

```
class Module > ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :course 
end
```

Could it be that 'Module' is a reserved keyword, and therefore I cannot create a class Module?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module` is "reserved" name in Ruby (since Ruby has build-in - and very important - `Module` class). This is probably source of your error.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I'll rename my Module class